# Firebase authentication works for web app but not as an Android trusted web application (TWA)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin, trusted-web-activity

What could be the issue that a **progressive web app** (PWA) with Firebase Google-Sign authentication works perfectly fine on the web but not if published as a **trusted web application** (TWA)?

The only error Android Studio shows while debugging:

> W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token
>   android.os.BinderProxy@ae7f0cd

What I tried and double checked:

- well-known sha256_cert_fingerprints is valid and available: (at: https://example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json)
- whitelisted my domain in Firebase

Code:
I'm using the [GoogleChromeLabs TWA example package](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/svgomg-twa). (Just changed the domain and name values.)

Comment: I have the exact same problem, it seems to be related to the redirection after authentication. I use Google signin popup, works perfectly on my  PWA but not on my TWA. Did you find anything ? I also use the google chrome labs example.

Comment: I didn't found a solution yet, sorry.

Comment: Do you have a sample App I can try to see what's wrong?

Comment: is this still happening? Did you find a way around?

Comment: @RishabhNigam I didn't found a solution yet, sorry.